# GR"A (GR"a) re: Sefirot and Kabbalah

Tags: internet

What is the GR"a ? Where on the internet can I find a resource for this and what does it have to do with the Sefirot and Kabbalah ?

Answer (score 3):

It is an acronym referring to Rabbi Elijah Kremer of Vilna. You can read more about him on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) or elsewhere on the internet. Among other things, he was a noted Kabbalist.

Comment: His name was not Kramer or Kremer. This surname began to be appended onto his name centuries after his time.

Answer (score 2):

GR"a is an acronym for [HaGaon Rabbi Eliyahu](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%94) who was also known as the Vilna Gaon.

Answer (score 1):

The GRA is the Vilna Gaon. He wrote a lot of books and commentaries, but if you're looking for his kabbalistic stuff, this is what I know of that's on the web:

1. [Sefer Yetzirah](http://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yetzirah.1) and the [GRA's commentary](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/jecira/gra_jec.htm) on it. (To clarify, he didn't write sefer yetzirah, but he wrote a commentary, and I figure you'll want to see the original to know what he's commenting on. Also there are several different versions of sefer yetzirah, and this is the "gra version" that he used).
2. [Aderet Eliyahu](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=150). The Gra's torah commentary. Although not strictly a kabbalistic work, it gives insight into his thought process.